# Restore In app Purchases in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

How do I save/link the user google account to their google API V3 in-app purchases in order to restore them after re-installing. Can someone provide an example method I can build upon?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have gone through the [document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) you might not have this question. It is clearly described there that the information is persistent on the Google Play servers even if the user uninstalls the application or if they change devices.

`getPurchases` call returns list of product's owned by the user. In response you can handle the state of user purchases.

Comment: Is that mean "developers don't need aware of non-consumable in app purchase restore transaction" right?

Comment: Outdated document link..as it deals with AIDL. Newer answer can help